# Apache Virtual Hosts on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, virtual-host

In /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, I have:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/bob/Sites/site1.local"
    <Directory /Users/bob/Sites/site1.local>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerName site2.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/bob/Sites/site2.local"
    <Directory /Users/bob/Sites/site2.local>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In /etc/hosts, I have:

```
127.0.0.1     site1.local
127.0.0.1     site2.local
```

Browsing to http://site1.local yields the correct site.  However, browsing to http://site2.local displays Site1's content.

Did I mis-configure something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In both your `localhost` and `site2.local` `<virtualHost>` declarations you have a `.` (dot) instead of a `:` (colon).

They should both be

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: Good eye :)  That was it.